# Just added mvc app to IIS 7, how to make it the site default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5

Sorry for the basic question but this is killing me. I added the mvc 3 app to the default site, and want to get the app instead of the welcome screen.

Comment: setup web-publishing in visual studio to publish site to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and choose Replace matching files with local copies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add it as a virtual directory?  If so you have to browse to that virtual directory, not just the machine.

e.g. `http://machine[:port]/virtual_directory`

The simplest way to set it as a new default site is to simply publish the site to c:\inetpub\wwwroot, since that's where the Default Web Site usually points.

Personally, however, I usually 'stop' the default web site, then create a new one on port 80 pointing to published folder; sometimes the original default site can come in handy.

That's unless, of course, you have one or specific host names (other than the machine name itself) that you intend to hit the site on, in which case you can leave the default web site there and add a new one with bindings on port 80 + each host name (you can only have one website with `*` as the hostname on a given port).

Comment: Thanks, it works now. I just had to leave a path blank as I added the application to the default site.

Comment: That said, I'm still not sure how IIS chooses which "page" to display. The "default document" list has none that match the HomeController that shows up.